# Get the value of itemLabel and itemVaue in backend Bean when submitted form

Tags: forms, primefaces, autocomplete

I have implemented primefaces autocomplete with custom converter and able to run code successully. Here is the code

```
<p:autoComplete styleClass="input-text full-wi0d00th0" placeholder="destin" var="search" value="#{searchDestination.desInput}" itemLabel="#{search.id}" itemValue="#{search.name}" converter="#{destinationConverter}" scrollHeight="150" minQueryLength="3"  completeMethod="#{searchDestination.getDestinationService}"
                                             effect="fade"></p:autoComplete>
```

This autocomplete is in h:form tag and on form submission  I am sending all form input's value (with this autocomplete) in backend bean. My question is how can I get the value of all attribute of autocomplete in managed bean(itemLabel,iteamValue,value).  I am not able to get theses autocomplete attribute value in my backend bean. I am not able to fund a solution yet

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: when your converters work, you have the full object server side after submitting. You can create a label and value based on that for the page, why can't you look those up server side then when the page is submitted. Maybe I fail to see the problem, but then please explain better and include an [mcve] of what you have up to now

Comment: Yes, suppose I have details.xhtml view and I have autocomplete(above code in my question) wrapped inside form in this page. When my form submitted it goes to the some detailsxxxBean.java file, I want the value of itemLabel, itemValue what value is going in autocomple in my detailsxxxBean.java file.

Comment: I have no clue what you mean by this comment. Does it work now?

Comment: @kukeljtje, I was explaining my question again with example, I hope I am able to explain my problem through earlier comment. No, it's not working.

Comment: Textual, hard to understand example. Please read [mcve]